# Joining a worker thread in a windows forms app

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

My program works like this:
I press a radio button which  opens the port.
Next i press a button "Read"  which starts a thread that reads data continously from the Serial Port using `port.ReadLine()` and prints it in a textbox;
I have another radio which should first **join** the thread and  after that close the port;the problem is the  printing goes well until i close the port when the UI freezes.

```
public Form1()
        {
            mythread = new Thread(ReadFct);
            myPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
            myPort.ReadTimeout = 3500;
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var t in Constants.ComboParameters)
                this.paramCombo.Items.Add(t);
            radioClose.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtonCheckedChanged);
            radioOpen.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtonCheckedChanged);


        }
```

Below is the function attached to the thread

```
void ReadFct()
        {
            string aux = "";
            while (readCondition)
            {
                if (myPort.IsOpen)

                    aux = myPort.ReadLine();


                this.SetText(aux);
            }

        }
```

Below is the radio button event handler

```
 public  void radioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
                if (radioOpen.Checked && !myPort.IsOpen)
                    try
                    {

                        myPort.Open();
                        mythread.Start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nu s-a putut deschide port-ul");
                    }

                if (radioClose.Checked && myPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    readCondition = false;
                    mythread.Join();

                    myPort.Close();

                    //  myPort.DataReceived -= DataReceivedHandler;

                }


 }
```

The read button function:

```
 private void readbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!myPort.IsOpen)
                MessageBox.Show("PORT NOT OPENED!");
            else
            {
                // myPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                readCondition = true;
                if (!mythread.IsAlive)
                {
                    mythread = new Thread(ReadFct);
                    mythread.Start();
                }

            }
```

I have used what MSDN suggest when changing control from another thread:

```
private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                StringTb del = new StringTb(SetText);
                this.Invoke(del, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
                SetData = text;

        }
```

Comment: And the `SetText` method is ...

Comment: it looks like this code will generate 2 radioButtonCheckedChanged events every time you make a change.  I think your code handles this, but ... each radio button generates an event for true->false and false-> true, so you click one button and both buttons create the same event.  I would separate the radioButtonCheckedChanged function into its 2 parts (since it really is 2 separate functions smashed together anyway).

Comment: The thread is stuck in the ReadLine() call, so it is never going to see the request to stop running.  Unless the device is sending data, that somewhat predictably is not happening.  Close() the serial port instead, that will bomb the ReadLine() call, catch the exception.  Or favor the DataReceived event instead of using a thread.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me i forgot.

Comment: I asked for `SetText` method because I was suspecting you use `Invoke` inside. If you `Join` the worker thread and call `Invoke` from inside, you've just got a deadlock.

Comment: And what would be a workaround?I am not very familiar with threading but i need it since i am reading and writing to port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you need, lacking a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the question. That said, the issue here is that the `Thread.Join()` method causes that thread to stop doing any other work, and the thread you use to call that method is the thread that handles all of the user interface. Worse, if your port never receives another newline, the thread you're waiting on will never terminate, because you're stuck waiting on the `ReadLine()` method. Even worse, even if you do get a newline, if that happens while you're stuck waiting on the `Thread.Join()`, the call to `Invoke()` will deadlock, because it needs the UI thread to do its work, and the `Thread.Join()` call is preventing it from getting the UI thread.

In other words, your code has multiple problems, any one of which could cause problems, but all of which together mean it just can't possibly work.

There are a variety of strategies to fix this, but IMHO the best is to use `await`. The first step in doing that is to change your I/O handling so that it's done asynchronously instead of dedicating a thread to it:

```
// Ideally, you should rename this method to "ReadFctAsync". I am leaving
// all names intact for the same of the example though.

async Task ReadFct()
{
    string aux = "";
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myPort.BaseStream))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            aux = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            // This will automatically work, because the "await" will automatically
            // resume the method execution in the UI thread where you need it.
            this.SetText(aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, instead of creating a thread explicitly, just create a `Task` object by calling the above:

```
public Form1()
{
    // In this approach, you can get rid of the "mythread" field altogether
    myPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
    myPort.ReadTimeout = 3500;
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (var t in Constants.ComboParameters)
        this.paramCombo.Items.Add(t);
    radioClose.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtonCheckedChanged);
    radioOpen.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtonCheckedChanged);
}

public async void radioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioOpen.Checked && !myPort.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            myPort.Open();
            await ReadFct();
            // Execution of this method will resume after the ReadFct() task
            // has completed. Which it will do only on throwing an exception.
            // This code doesn't have any continuation after the "await", except
            // to handle that exception.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // This block will catch the exception thrown when the port is
            // closed. NOTE: you should not catch "Exception". Figure out what
            // *specific* exceptions you expect to happen and which you can
            // handle gracefully. Any other exception can mean big trouble,
            // and doing anything other than logging and terminating the process
            // can lead to data corruption or other undesirable behavior from
            // the program.
            MessageBox.Show("Nu s-a putut deschide port-ul");
        }

        // Return here. We don't want the rest of the code executing after the
        // continuation, because the radio button state might have changed
        // by then, and we really only want this call to do work for the button
        // that was selected when the method was first called. Note that it
        // is probably even better if you just break this into two different
        // event handlers, one for each button that might be checked.
        return;
    }

    if (radioClose.Checked && myPort.IsOpen)
    {
        // Closing the port should cause `ReadLineAsync()` to throw an
        // exception, which will terminate the read loop and the ReadFct()
        // task
        myPort.Close();
    }
}
```

In the above, I have completely ignored the `readbtn_Click()` method. Lacking a good MCVE, it's not clear what role that button plays in the overall scheme. You *seem* to have a radio button group (of two buttons) that control whether the port is open or closed. It is not clear why then you have an additional regular button that is seemingly able to also open the port and start reading, independently of the radio group.

If you want that extra button, it seems to me that all it ought to do is change the radio group state, by checking the "open" radio button. Then let the radio group buttons handle the port state and reading. If you need more specific advice as to how to fully integrate my code example above with your entire UI, you will need to provide more detail, preferably in a new question. That new question must include a good MCVE.